# Image of Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\alpha \in \mathrm{End}(V)$ for some vector space $V$ and let  $m_\alpha=\prod_{l=1}^n p_l^{a_l}$ be the minimum polynomial and $c_\alpha=\prod_{l=1}^n p_l^{b_l}$ be the characteristic polynomial, all $p_j$ are pairwise distinct, irreducible and normalized.

I want to show that $\mathrm{im}((\prod_{l\neq k}p_l^{b_l})(\alpha))=\mathrm{im}((\prod_{l\neq k}p_l^{a_l})(\alpha))$. What is the easiest way to show this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $\;k\;$ in those products at the end? What does taking the product over $\;l\neq k\;$ mean at all? And when you say the $\;p_i\;$'s (which are irreducible polynomials, right?) are "normalized, do you actually mean theyr are monic polynomials, i.e. with leading coefficient equal to one?